# cannot convert type long to T, here T is an Enum's value

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

```
  T  bitmask = (T)PermissionBitMask;
  bool hasAccess = (bitmask & (T)operation) == (T)operation;
```

// here T is an Enum type of long value , PermissionBitMask is an long value of Enum, while operation is an integer value.

```
public bool CheckAccess<T>(int operation) where T : Enum 
{ 
    bool hasAccess = false; 
    T bitmask = (T)_permission.PermissionBitMask; 
    hasAccess = bitmask & (T)operation == (T)operation; 
    return hasAccess; 
}
```

Comment: can you post the `actual` exception message?

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example code

Comment: getting this compile time error- CS0030 - Cannot convert type 'int' to 'T'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Enum.ToObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.toobject?view=netframework-4.7.2) method as:

```
    private static T IntegerToEnum<T>(int i)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("...");
        }
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), i);
    }
```

and

```
    private static T LongToEnum<T>(long i)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("...");
        }
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), i);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering enums are convertible you can constrain `IConvertible` on `T`:

```
public bool HasAccess<T>(T permissionBitMask, long operation) where T: IConvertible
{
    long bitmask = permissionBitMask.ToInt64(null);
    return (bitmask & operation) == operation;
}
```

And if you can use C# 7.3 also `System.Enum` can be constrained.